# SQLite not recognising django table- or the other way around?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I have researched this problem a lot by now but I can't seem to get a result. I am trying to insert new values into and query tables into a django established table-database.
It seems that a number of people have had this reoccurring problem over the years. I have tried to rectify it both on my Mac and on a desk Linux server both on django 1.8 and 1.9 but the problem remains after migrations...

Based on the advice that I have seen on similar posts I have tried the following:

```
      # to update the database to establish inputs
      ./manage.py

      # inserting this into INSTALLED_APPS
      django.contrib.sites 

      # modifying settings.py as below...
      import os
      PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
      'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'mysite.sqlite3'),

      # specifying the full pathname to the database in settings.py
       'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/project/homemsc/username/trydjango19/mysite/db.sqlite3')
```

However in the case of each of these modifications when inserting values in SQLite "Error: No such table exists" is returned. I know for sure that it is something subtle that I'm doing when setting up the database....

Answer (score 0):

You have to create that table in your database. You can do it by hand (which is not recommended) or create django migration using:

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

and then apply that migration using

```
./manage.py migrate
```